# VB.Net Days Between Dates

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to calculate the days that have passed between today and a date in the past using the following code:

```
 CaseOpenDays.Text = (DateTime.Now.Subtract(CDate(DateReported.Text)))
```

Where `CaseOpenDays` is a label and `DateReported.text` is also a label.

I'm having this error thrown:

> Value of type 'System.TimeSpan' cannot be converted to 'String'

What am I missing here?

Comment: It would appear I'm being downvoted for not accepting someones answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `TimeSpan.Days` or `TimeSpan.TotalDays`:

```
Dim timeSinceReporting As TimeSpan = DateTime.Now - CDate(DateReported.Text)
CaseOpenDays.Text = CInt(timeSinceReporting.TotalDays).ToString()
```

Another way is [`TimeSpan.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
CaseOpenDays.Text = timeSinceReporting.ToString("dd")
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to transform the TimeSpan result in some textual thing for example calling ToString on it

```
CaseOpenDays.Text = DateTime.Now.Subtract(CDate(DateReported.Text)).ToString
```

Answer (score 1):

`(DateTime.Now.Subtract(CDate(DateReported.Text)))` returns a timespan rather than a string :)

Answer (score 1):

When you substract two DateTime structures, you end up with [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) structure. Which is pretty logical. Your TimeSpan is a structure that has methods and cannot be converted directly to a String...

Here you can do :

```
Dim ts As TimeSpan = DateTime.Now.Subtract(CDate(DateReported.Text))
CaseOpenDays.Text = ts.Days.toString()
```

You can also use TotalDays method. [Here is the explanation of the difference.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.timespan.totaldays(v=vs.110).aspx)